# OpenLDAP ACLs are not working

Tags: linux, fedora, openldap

First things first, I'm currently working with an OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.36 on a Fedora release 19 (Schrödinger’s Cat).

I've just install the openldap with yum and my configuration is the following one:

```
##### OpenLDAP Default configuration #####
#
##### OpenLDAP CORE CONFIGURATION #####
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema

pidfile         /var/lib/ldap/slapd.pid

loglevel trace

##### Default Schema #####

database mdb
directory /var/lib/ldap/
maxsize 1073741824

suffix "dc=domain,dc=tld"
rootdn "cn=root,dc=domain,dc=tld"
rootpw {SSHA}SECRETP@SSWORD


##### Default ACL #####
access to attrs=userpassword
        by self write
        by group.exact="cn=administrators,ou=builtin,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=tld" write
        by anonymous auth
        by * none
```

I launch my OpenLDAP service using:

```
/usr/sbin/slapd -u ldap -h ldapi:/// ldap:/// -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf
```

As you can see it's a pretty simple ACL which aim to allow access to the userPassword attribute to a specific group read only, then to the owner read and write to anonymous requiring auth and refuse the access to everyone else.

The problem is: Even using a valid user with correct password my ldapsearch ends with zero informations retrieved from the directory, plus I've got a strange response on the result line.

```
# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
```

here is the ldapsearch request:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap.domain.tld -W -b dc=domain,dc=tld -s sub -D cn=user,ou=service,ou=employees,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=tld
```

I did not specify any filter as I want to check that ldapsearch is correctly printing only allowed attribute.

---

@SvW here is what I've put on my slapd.conf according to your exemple and OpenLDAP Documentation:

I edited my slapd.conf with the following ACLs rules eliminating group.exact for easier debug:

```
access to *
    by self read
    by anonymous auth
    by * none

access to attrs=userpassword
    by self write
    by anonymous auth
    by * none
```

but once again, I'm facing the

> 32 No Such object error

when I'm trying the following ldapsearches:

```
 ldapsearch -W -s sub -D cn=user,ou=service,ou=employees,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=tld -b dc=domain,dc=tld userpassword=*
```

or without filter:

```
 ldapsearch -W -s sub -D cn=user,ou=service,ou=employees,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=tld -b dc=domain,dc=tld
```

Comment: Please provide informations regarding the query used and the content of the directory. Also check if my modification to the ACL is correct.

Comment: I just update the question with the requested informations. If you see something, let me know!

Comment: Did you actually *add* any records to the LDAP database? You are running this in a very strange way anyway.

Comment: Yep, I've got already existing users and groups and informations on the ldap database. What do you mean by strange way? If I perform the same search using the administrator user, everything is fine (which is normal) and the ldapsearch is returning correct informations depending on the filters used or all informations contained if no filters provided.

Comment: The usual way to use OpenLDAP is to run it as a service and to configure it via the `cn=config` database.  Can you read records if using the `rootdn` user?

Comment: Yes, using the rootdn everything is fine, I've got the ability to read anything on the ldap. I think that I'm a little bit lost with the cn=config style configuration as I've always perform any operation on my ldap using ldif or the slapd.conf file but it seems that since some versions OpenLDAP have change the way you populate the database.

Answer (score 0):

To test, try to add

```
access to * by * read
```

*after* the first ACL entry.

This should still restrict the `userpassword` but explicitly allow you to read all other fields (I believe OpenLDAP adds implicitly `to * by * none` otherwise, see section 8.3.4 of the [documentation](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html)).

**Edit:**

Does it restrict the password field? This is not very clear from your comment. If not, remember @Janne's answer and check if the spelling for `userPassword` is correct. If it is working, you'll have to start from there to add restrictions. The following is untested, but should work (it might be too restrictive though).

```
access to * 
    by self read 
    by group.exact="cn=administrators,ou=builtin,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=tld" write
    by * none
```

Comment: Adding this ACL is allowing me to correctly display ALL informations contained on my LDAP. So now I know that my slapd.conf file is working but I have the problem that I don't want authenticated people to be able to browse my directory, just their own attributes or a specific set of. Thanks for your help by the way :D

Comment: @DrI: This is essentially a new question, but see my edit anyway.

Comment: please see my own answer upper, as formatting is not working on comments unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
access to attrs=userPassword
```

instead of your previous

```
access to attrs=userpassword
```

Comment: Indeed, that was the case that I used during my previous tests and it's not working neither :(